# How to organise a webpacked vue.js application served by an express/koa backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, koa

I am having some difficulty with setting up an easy to debug vue.js project in combination with a koa server. The command `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot` from the webpack-simple generated configuration seems to be a nice thing, but what is the convention for using this with koa/express?

One solution that i've found is using pm2 to launch the webpack-dev-server for vue and the backend at the same time, but then i think this means i need a copied version of the initial landing vue.js app page which i'm currently serving from a koa route on /. Also it's kind of confusing for me to think about these two servers and it feels strange.

So, i think i must be doing it wrong! Could someone please explain a nice conventional way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to use webpack-dev-server with your own Node backend, you'll want to look into using [`proxy`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy).

Basically, the idea is that you run your `webpack-dev-server` on one port (for example, port `3000`) and you run your Node server on another port (for example, port `3001`). You just need to tell webpack to forward your server-side requests to your Node backend.

You can do this by adding a `proxy` property to the `devServer` setting in your **webpack.config.js** file. For example:

```
devServer: {
  ...
  proxy: {
    '/api/**': {
      target: 'http://localhost:3001',
      secure: false
    }
  }
}
```

Now, any requests that start with `/api/` will go to your Node backend. So if you do something like:

```
fetch('/api/users').then(...)
```

This request will be proxied to your Node server. You will just want to make sure you prefix all your server-side routes with `/api/`.

To automatically prefix all your routes in Koa, you can just do the following:

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const Router = require('koa-router')

const app = new Koa()
const router = new Router({ prefix: '/api' })

// GET /api/users
router.get('/users', async ctx => {
  ...
})

app.use(router.routes())
app.use(router.allowedMethods())
```

If you're using Express, you can prefix by doing the following:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const router = express.Router()

// GET /api/users
router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  ...
})

app.use('/api', router)
```